# Spring + Tiles - Show error page without changing URL?

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

How would I go about showing users a generic error page (such as 404) without changing the URL in the browser?

So for example, if the user goes to a page `/happy/fun/times` but no such tiles view/mapping exists in my web application, I want the URL to stay as `/happy/fun/times` but show them the tiles view of `/error/404` instead.

Also, on a related note how would I do this with all errors, such as 500 errors or 403 errors? Or even exceptions that somehow may get through?

I've tried using the web.xml to do the following:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error/500</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/404</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/error/403</location>
</error-page>
<error-page> 
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type> 
    <location>/error/general</location> 
</error-page>
```

however that doesn't seem to work. If I want, I can change the location to '/WEB-INF/jsp/error/404.jsp', then the 404 errors are caught by the web.xml. However, then it just displays the contents of the '404.jsp' file instead of the tiles view '/error/404' that I actually want displayed.

Comment: I don't do Spring MVC, but doesn't just specifying them as `<error-page>` in `web.xml` the usual way work for you?

Answer (score 2):

How I ended up doing this was with the following code:

/WEB-INF/jsp/error/404.jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>

<!-- insert the view -->
<tiles:insertDefinition name="baseLayout" > 
    <tiles:putAttribute name="body" value="<p> Error 404!! </p>" />
</tiles:insertDefinition>
```

web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/403.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to handle exceptions by type

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/uncaughtException.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

or this to handle by HTTP error code

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

If you want a spring controller or a spring view to resolve the exception then you need to declare a Spring bean of type SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key=".DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
            <prop key=".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".TypeMismatchException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".MissingServletRequestParameterException">resourceNotFound</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In the JSP page, you can access the exception instance via ${exception}.

Comment: OK, that works to display the error, however if I want to use a tiles view instead of a jsp file is that possible? What I've been trying to do is use something like '/error/404' instead of '/WEB-INF/jsp/error/404.jsp' because I'd like to have tiles control what the user sees (so they can see the navigation and stuff like that). Is that possible or do I have to manually include the navigation and stuff in the 404.jsp?